# C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command compiling opencv for QT

Tags: windows, qt, opencv, cmake

i want compile opencv for QT. i use this tutorial

http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml

in step 8 i have this error:

```
C:\opencv_bin1>mingw32-make 
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.obj 
'C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,   
  operable program or batch file. 
 3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\build.make:53: recipe for target
 '3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.obj' failed                                     mingw32-make[2]: *** [3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.obj] Error 1  CMakeFiles\Makefile2:269: recipe for target '3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all' failed                                                                      mingw32-make[1]: *** [3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all] Error 2            makefile:112: recipe for target 'all' failed                                    mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i think it is from path variable but i don't see mistake in it.
any idea?

```
EDIT
```

when i use make instead of mingw32-make :
[image]

```
path variables:
```

user variables:

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\op    
ncv\build\x64\vc10\bin\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio    
10.0\Common7\Tools\;C:\jom\jom.exe\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake  
2.6\bin\;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin\;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\;
```

system variables:

```
    C:\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\Inprise\vbroker\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.
1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 
2.8\bin\;C:\Windows\System32\;
```

i download msys and add it's bin folder to path. Now when i enter in opencv directory and type make it wrote:

```
C:\opencv_Bin>make   
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]  
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `make` instead (i.e. the one from MSYS distribution), and avoid using `mingw32-make` (from MinGW distribution) in future to avoid problems with paths. In fact, `mingw32-make` has some other pitfalls, including missing functionality, and you definitely don't want to deal with that. Extract from MinGW Wiki:

> **What's the difference between make and mingw32-make?**
>
> The "native" (i.e.: MSVCRT dependent) port of make is lacking in some functionality and has modified functionality due to the lack of POSIX on Win32. There also exists a version of make in the MSYS distribution that is dependent on the MSYS runtime. This port operates more as make was intended to operate and gives less headaches during execution. Based on this, the MinGW developers/maintainers/packagers decided it would be best to rename the native version so that both the "native" version and the MSYS version could be present at the same time without file name collision.

As a result, what you want is to ask CMake to use `MSYS Makefiles` generator, instead of `MinGW Makefiles`.

### Update

---

You have some wrong `make` in your `PATH` environment variable. Just look: `Inprise Corp.`, what is that !@#$? Whatever it is, it is definitely not MSYS `make`. Clean up your `PATH` and make sure that you have MSYS `make` in it. Check it via running `make --version`, and you should see the following:

```
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I can't tell you. Nobody knows your environment better than you. You'll have to find it yourself. You actually surprised me, c'mon you can't be so bad... don't you know how to use search for `make.exe` file on your computer? As an alternative, you could open MSYS Bash and type `which make.exe`.

Comment: make.exe only exist in borland delphi and nmake in qt folder

Comment: So obviously it is `make.exe` from Borland Delphi then, that should be removed from the `PATH`.

Comment: i delete it and now when i type make it wrote: 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,     operable program or batch file.

Comment: That's because you didn't add MSYS `make.exe` into `PATH`.

Comment: i don't know what is it and what is it's address until add it.

Comment: Download **[MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/msys%2B7za%2Bwget%2Bsvn%2Bgit%2Bmercurial%2Bcvs-rev13.7z/download)**, unpack it, and add `bin` directory to the `PATH`.

Comment: ops my internet connection is slow i will try that tomorrow morning and hop that work. thanks for your replies i will accept your question if it worked. there is no another suggestion ?

Comment: Nope, that's all you need, just get MSYS. One thing I encourage you to do, is to learn what MSYS and MinGW actually are, why you need them, and what is Make! Definitely do this, as you seem to be very very new to all that stuff, and it's going to get harder if you don't grasp these basics now.

Comment: Something is wrong with you `PATH`. I've shown you the sample output that you should expect. Some Microsoft `make` is still in your `PATH`.

Comment: when i type `make --version` i see exactly your output. but when i type `make` in opencv directory  i saw  `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]  
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

Comment: Is there `makefile` in that directory? Did you generate `MSYS Makefiles` with CMake?

Comment: yes makefile is exist in opencv_bin directory. i only add bin folder of msys to path . how can i generate it with msys?